# Simple c++ continuous calculator, can't exit the program

Tags: c++

I have made this simple calculator in C++. It accepts input continuously, but I run into trouble defining my operation variable as a char because it leaves me with no way to quit the program. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

 int main(){
    long double num1, num2; char operation;
    std::cout << "Welcome to the calculator!\n\nInput numbers and operations to begin. (2+2) Then hit enter.\n\nThe calculator will continue to expect an operation and number (e.g. +6)\nuntil you enter \"q\" as an operation.\n\nEnter \"q\" as an operation to quit.\n\n";
    std::cin >> num1 >> operation >> num2;
    do{
        switch(operation){
            case '+':
                num2 += num1;
                break;
            case '-':
                num2 -= num1;
                break;
            case '/':
                num2 /= num1;
                break;
            case '*':
                num2 *= num1;
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << "Not a valid operation. Try again.";
                break;
        }
        std::cout << num2;
    } while (std::cin >> operation >> num1);
    return 0;
}
```

The program runs fine and works perfectly, I just don't know how to quit. I've tried making 'q' a case to return 0, but it doesn't seem to work because my do-while expects 2 inputs... Any thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::cin >> num1 >> operation >> num2;
do
{
switch(operation){
case '+': num2 += num1; break;
case '-': num2 -= num1; break;
case '/': num2 /= num1; break;
case '*': num2 *= num1; break;
default: std::cout << "Not a valid operation. Try again."; break; }
std::cout << num2;
std::cin >> operation;
if (operation == 'q') break;
else std::cin >> num1;
}
while (1);
```

**Sample I/O**
3+4
7+3
10q
end
3+4

Comment: Okay, now I have a new problem. If I enter 2-9, it spits out 7, not -7. But if I enter 2+-9 it spits out -7. Why is it doing that?

Comment: If I enter 2-9, it spits out -7 in my console. Have you modified the code?

Comment: No, I have the same code. Interestingly, If I pass the first run through with a positive number, it displays negative numbers fine all times after that. Nevermind, I see. as suggested by @Dieter Lücking mentioned below, my '-' and '/' operations were messed up. Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Well now it works right the first time and is messed up afterwards. I feel like this is harder than it should be

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this.

```
    std::cin >> num1 >> operation >> num2;    

do{
    std::cout << "Enter operation";
    std::cin >>operation;
    switch(operation){
        case '+':
            num2 += num1;
            break;
        case '-':
            num2 -= num1;
            break;
        case '/':
            num2 /= num1;
            break;
        case '*':
            num2 *= num1;
            break;
        case 'q':
            return 0;      //or exit(0);
        default:
            std::cout << "Not a valid operation. Try again.";
            break;
    }
    std::cout << num2;
} while (true);
```

Comment: This method doesn't allow me to just tack on "-100" to my already existing number, the user would then have to enter num1, an operation, and num2 again.

Comment: ok, if you want to perform operation on same numbers, so now look at the solution.

Comment: wouldn't this just loop forever printing e.g. 2+2, 4, 6, 8, etc.?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to take operation from user. now it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take.

```
int main()
{
   long double num1, num2;
   char operation;
   bool stop = false;
   std::cout << "Welcome to the calculator!\n\nInput numbers and operations to begin. (2+2) Then hit enter.\n\nThe calculator will continue to expect an operation and number (e.g. +6)\nuntil you enter \"q\" as an operation.\n\nEnter \"q\" as an operation to quit.\n\n";

   std::cin >> num1 >> operation >> num2;

   do{
       switch(operation) {

           case '+':
              num2 += num1;
              break;

           case '-':
              num2 -= num1;
              break;

           case '/':
              num2 /= num1;
              break;

           case '*':
              num2 *= num1;
              break;

           default:
              std::cout << "Not a valid operation. Try again.";
              break;
       }
       std::cout << num2 << std::endl;

       // Skip till the end of the line.
       while ( std::cin.get() != '\n');

       // Read the next operation.
       std::cin >> operation;
       if ( operation == 'q' )
       {
          stop = true;
       }
       else
       {
          std::cin >> num1;
       }

   } while (std::cin.good() && !std::cin.eof() && !stop);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case 'q': exit(0);
```

or

```
case 'q': std::exit;
```

Don't forget to add cstdio header file.